# Непонятное поведение JS

Tags: javascript, html

ВОПРОС ПОПРАВЛЕН И УТОЧНЕН!

Есть код, где переключение между ссылками очищает `"результирующий" div`. Но только пытаюсь сделать ссылку `"постраничности"`, то очистка происходит, но окно закрывается. Голову уже сломал куда копать - ведь ситуации идентичны, даже вызовы методов пробовал реализовать один в один, все равно окно исчезает. Окно - это всплывающий `div`.

Если очистку отключить, то результат на фото. Если включить div становится скрытым, но при нажатии на показ в div находится нужный результат. Почему же становится не видимым. Еще хочу добавить, что при дебаге блок не исчезает, а отрабатывает как нужно.

Это код с очисткой (пробовал разные методы - здесь 2 варианта)

```
if (clear_box) {
    box_result.html("");

   /* box_result.remove();
   $('.nc_result').append("<div id='notify_body'></div>");
    box_result = $('#notify_body');*/

}
```

добавил пример работающей ссылки на фото без очистки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты лучше опиши, что ты хотел реализовать...

Comment: и какой фреймворк используется

Comment: Реализую постраничность, без фреймфорка. если очистку убираю, то все работает только без очистки (фото в описание добавлю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину, у меня в методе при необходимости идет запрос на сервер, в это время и возникает проблема, отправил выполнение метода через другой с задержкой в 1 миллисекунду. Заработало. НО ПО МНЕ ЭТО ОГРОМЕННЫЙ КОСТЫЛЬ. Буду структуру кода менять. Всем спасибо

Comment: Да, это дикий костыль. Каким способом идёт запрос на сервер?

Comment: аякс. у меня партийная загрузка (сначала новые данные, после более поздние при необходимости)

Comment: так почему бы не запускать функции после успешной обработки запроса? по `success` например